# Error 500 in the registration of new addresses for prestashop store 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Prestashop store is showing error 500 after the customer fills out the address registration form and clicks save. I put it in debug mode and the message of the attached image appeared. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2gzA.png)

Comment: can you edit the file mentioned? on line 62 there is something wrong with the "name" key

Comment: please refrain from adding images with the external links, instead add error /code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with the given information it is not possible to give a definitive answer. However, one thing is obvious: in template `address-form.tpl` Prestashop tries to access some array with index `name` but name is not defined there.

I checked out your site `dadpet.com.br` and it uses the `classic` theme, so it's unlikely that there is any programming error in it. In file `themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/address-form.tpl` (this template is used to render address form fields) there is only one instance where index `name` is being accessed and that is where it checks if field name is alias:

```php-template
  {if $field.name eq "alias" and $customer.is_guest}
    {* we don't ask for alias here if customer is not registered *}
  {else}
    {$smarty.block.parent}
  {/if}
```

You can solve the issue by checking if the `name` is set by modifying the if statement:

```php-template
  {if isset($field.name) and $field.name eq "alias" and $customer.is_guest}
```

You will not get an error, but the underlying issue is that some address field does not have a name set. Perhaps you tried adding some custom field or some module is adding it and not constructing it properly.